# How do you get the extreme y-axis values in HighCharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

In Highcharts I can use the xAxis event to get the extremes of the current view (the x-axis boundaries), but how do I get the Y-axis values for each series at those boundaries?

```
    xAxis: {
      events: {
        setExtremes: function (e) {

          $('#report').html(
            '<b>The new time interval is: (' +
              Highcharts.dateFormat("%m/%d/%Y", e.min) +
            ', ' + 
              Highcharts.dateFormat("%m/%d/%Y", e.max) +
              ').</b><br />The values at those boundaries are: <b>(Y1, Y2)</b>.'
          );

        }
      }
    },
```

Here is a link to a jsFiddle of what I want: https://jsfiddle.net/MrSnrub/eex337m8

As you resize using the rangeSelector you will get different dates. I want to get the min and max values at those dates. How do I do that?

**UPDATE:** I have been asked to provide my updated code, and here it is:

HTML:

```
<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 600px"></div>
<div id="div-new-legend" style="font: 0.8em sans-serif">
</div>

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/three-series-1000-points.js"></script>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(function () {
  $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

    legend: {
        enabled: true,
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        layout: 'vertical',
        width: 200,
        borderColor: 'black',
        borderWidth: 0.5
      },

      xAxis: {
        events: {
          setExtremes: function (e) {

            // Highcharts is starting the processedYdata one element
            // early, so we'll grab the first element to be the 
            // start date's Y-axis min data, not the zeroth
            // element. (max_date looks OK.)
            var msft_data = e.target.series[0].processedYData;
            var msft_min = msft_data[1];
            var msft_max = msft_data[msft_data.length - 1];
            var msft_change = ((msft_max - msft_min)/(msft_min) * 100).toFixed(2);
            var span_msft_change = (msft_change > 0) 
              ? ('<span class="pos">' + msft_change + '%</span>') 
              : ('<span class="neg">' + msft_change + '%</span>'); 

            var adbe_data = e.target.series[1].processedYData;
            var adbe_min = adbe_data[1];
            var adbe_max = adbe_data[adbe_data.length -1];
            var adbe_change = ((adbe_max - adbe_min)/(adbe_min) * 100).toFixed(2);
            var span_adbe_change = (adbe_change > 0) 
              ? ('<span class="pos">' + adbe_change + '%</span>') 
              : ('<span class="neg">' + adbe_change + '%</span>'); 

            var googl_data = e.target.series[2].processedYData;
            var googl_min = googl_data[1];
            var googl_max = googl_data[googl_data.length -1];
            var googl_change = ((googl_max - googl_min)/(googl_min) * 100).toFixed(2);
            var span_googl_change = (googl_change > 0) 
              ? ('<span class="pos">' + googl_change + '%</span>') 
              : ('<span class="neg">' + googl_change + '%</span>'); 

            $('#div-new-legend').html(

'<table id="new-legend">' +
'  <tr>' +
'    <th>&nbsp;</th>' +
'    <th>Start</th>' +
'    <th>End</th>' +
'    <th>Change</th>' +
'  </tr>' +
'  <tr>' +
'    <td class="stock">' + e.target.series[0].name + '</td>' +
'    <td>' + msft_min + '</td>' +
'    <td>' + msft_max + '</td>' +
'    <td>' + span_msft_change + '</td>' +
'  </tr>' +
'  <tr>' +
'    <td class="stock">' + e.target.series[1].name + '</td>' +
'    <td>' + adbe_min + '</td>' +
'    <td>' + adbe_max + '</td>' +
'    <td>' + span_adbe_change + '</td>' +
'  </tr>' +
'  <tr>' +
'    <td class="stock">' + e.target.series[2].name + '</td>' +
'    <td>' + googl_min + '</td>' +
'    <td>' + googl_max + '</td>' +
'    <td>' + span_googl_change + '</td>' +
'  </tr>' +
'</table>'
          );
        }
      }
    },

    rangeSelector: {
      selected: 1
    },

    series: [{
      name: 'Microsoft',
      data: MSFT
    }, {
      name: 'Adobe',
      data: ADBE
    }, {
      name: 'Google',
      data: GOOGL
    }]
  });
});
```

CSS:

```
.pos {
  color: green;
}
.neg {
  color: red;
}

#new-legend-header {
  background-color: #e7f0f9;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.5em;
  width: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
#new-legend {
  margin-top: 0.5em;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-collapse: collapse;  
  width: 300px;
  font-family: "Lucida Grande","Lucida Sans Unicode",Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: normal;
}
#new-legend th,
#new-legend td {
  padding: 0;
}

#new-legend td.stock {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 0.5em;
}
#new-legend td {
  text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was seeing the Y-values on the previous click because I was using the **setExtremes** event to form my HTML. There is another event called **afterSetExtremes** that works specifically for this purpose.

Updated JavaScript code:

```
$(function () {

  function create_new_legend(e) {

    var html = `
<table id="new-legend">
  <tr>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
    <th class="price">Start</th>
    <th class="price">End</th>
    <th class="price">Change</th>
  </tr>
`;

    for (var i = 0; i < e.target.series.length; ++i) {
      var series_name = e.target.series[i].name;

      // Skip over the navigator.
      if (series_name.toLowerCase().trim() ==
          "Navigator".toLowerCase().trim())
      {
        continue;
      }

      var series_min_date = e.target.series[i].processedXData[0];
      var series_max_date = e.target.series[i].processedXData[
        e.target.series[i].processedXData.length - 1];

      var series_processed_y_data = e.target.series[i].processedYData;
      var series_min_y_data = series_processed_y_data[0].toFixed(2);
      var series_max_y_data = series_processed_y_data[
        series_processed_y_data.length - 1].toFixed(2);

      var series_data_change = ((series_max_y_data - series_min_y_data)/(series_min_y_data) * 100).toFixed(2);

      var series_css_class = (series_data_change > 0)
        ? 'pos' : ((series_data_change == 0)
                    ? 'zero' : 'neg');

      html += `
  <tr>
    <td class="stock">` + series_name + `</td>
    <td class="price">` + series_min_y_data + `</td>
    <td class="price">` + series_max_y_data + `</td>
    <td class="price"><span class="` + series_css_class + '">' + series_data_change + `%</td>
  </tr>
`;
    } // end iterate through each series

    html += `
</table>
`;
    $('#div-new-legend').html(html);

  } // end function create_new_legend(e)

  $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

    chart: {
      renderTo: 'container',
      events: {
        load: create_new_legend
      }
    },

    legend: {
      enabled: true,
      align: 'right',
      verticalAlign: 'middle',
      layout: 'vertical',
      width: 200,
      borderColor: 'black',
      borderWidth: 0.5
    },

    xAxis: {
      events: {
        afterSetExtremes: create_new_legend
      }
    },

    rangeSelector: {
        selected: 1
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Microsoft',
        data: MSFT
    }, {
        name: 'Adobe',
        data: ADBE
    }, {
        name: 'Google',
        data: GOOGL
    }]
  });
});
```

Updated CSS code:

```
.pos {
  color: green;
}
.neg {
  color: red;
}
.zero {
  color: black;
}

#new-legend {
  margin-top: 0.5em;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-collapse: collapse;  
  width: 300px;
  font-family: "Lucida Grande","Lucida Sans Unicode",Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: normal;
}
#new-legend th,
#new-legend td {
  padding: 0;
}

#new-legend td.stock {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 0.5em;
}
.price {
  text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle version of it ?

Comment: Did it myself. maybe someone might able to use it :) http://jsfiddle.net/Lejq5crL/

Answer (score 0):

**Updated:** According with the comments:

```
var data = e.target.series[0].processedYData; // Get the y-axis data.
var dataMin = data[0]; // The first value.
var dataMax = data[data.length-1]; // The last value.
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

    xAxis: {
      events: {
        setExtremes: function(e) {
          // alert('The new time interval is: min: ' + 
          //   Highcharts.dateFormat("%m/%d/%Y", e.max));


          var data = e.target.series[0].processedYData;
          var dataMin = data[0];
          var dataMax = data[data.length - 1];



          $('#report').html(
            '<b>The new time interval is: (' +
            Highcharts.dateFormat("%m/%d/%Y", e.min) +
            ', ' +
            Highcharts.dateFormat("%m/%d/%Y", e.max) +
            ').</b><br />The values at those boundaries are: <b>(' + dataMin + ', ' + dataMax + ')</b>.');

        }
      }
    },

    rangeSelector: {
      selected: 1
    },

    series: [{
      name: 'MSFT',
      data: MSFT
    }]
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 600px"></div>
<div id="report" style="font: 0.8em sans-serif"></div>

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/three-series-1000-points.js"></script>
```

[image]

Comment: That does not appear to be correct, unfortunately. For example, if I resize it so that the x-axis minimum data point is May 7, 2015, the dataMin point reads 46.14, but the actual MSFT stock price data point for that date is 47.75. Shouldn't they be the same?

Comment: Not necessarily, the value of MSFT read when the mouse is over. You must see the minimum and maximum values of the visible range.

Comment: I don't think that's what he's looking for. yAxis.getExtremes would give you the maximum and minimum y values in a dataset, while the OP wants to find out the y values corresponding to xAxis.getExtremes.

Comment: Rahul Sharma is correct. That is exactly what I want.

Comment: Hi guys, I've updated my answer. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I tried that too, doesn't seem to work properly. It seems that the extremes are not actually the  extreme 'hoverable' points. If you try this out with any range which is not maximum and minimum (for example try Jan-Apr), the result would not be correct.

Comment: Sorry it's still not correct. For example, for the date 4/26/2016, the actual data point is $48.03, but the processedYdata value says $47.87

Comment: It is kinda buggy with the zoom selector. Try clicking on different ranges, at some point it starts showing odd values.

Apparently we are faced with a bug.

Comment: After working with this for a couple days I've figured out that the processedYData values are one element off. The 0th subscript is not the minimum, the 1st subscript is. (See my updated jsFiddle). 

Also, the values that are appearing on the new legend are one click behind. In other words, if you click on 3m, then on 6m, it will show the 3m value. How do you get these values to reflect the current click?

Comment: Hi @MrSnrub, can you update your post with your last jsFiddle?

Comment: @MrSnrub that is not true either. I have tried that and that is not always the case. The problem is, I think, processedYData seems to have the points which are plotted on the graph, but in some cases the extremes are not hoverable because they are too close to the edge. To test that they are not always one element off, changing the left bound of the range keeping the right as it was.

Comment: Yes, exactly @RahulSharma.